# sublime text 2: ignore more than one file extension for

Tags: sublime-text-2

How do you ignore more than one file extension your project settings. The documentation provides an example of just one file setting being ignored:

```
    {
        "path": "docs",
        "name": "Documentation",
        "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.css"]
    }
```

[Source](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [JSON](http://www.json.org) file, and the `[ ]` square brackets indicate an array, or a list. Hence:

```
"file_exclude_patterns": ["*.css", "*.js"]
```